# Select Distinct Certain Columns From Result

Tags: sql, select, distinct

Let say I have 3 tables :

1. Author table (ID, AuthorName)
2. Genre table (ID, GenreName)
3. Books table (ID, Date, Genre, Author)

Where Genre and Author are Foreign Keys (ID) of Genre and Author tables.

Here I use :

```
Select Books.ID, Books.Date, Genre.GenreName, Author.AuthorName
From Books, Genre, Author
Where Books.Genre = Genre.ID
   AND Books.Author = Author.ID
Order By Books.ID Desc;
```

to get this result :

| ID |  Date | Genre | Author |

---------------------------------

| 1 | 4/2/11 | Action | A |

| 2 | 7/7/11 | Horror | B |

| 3 | 18/8/11 | Action | A |

| 4 | 3/10/11 | Comedy| C |

| 5 | 16/7/11 | Horror | D |

| 6 | 29/7/11 | Horror | B |

| 7 | 12/5/11 | Comedy| E |

| 8 | 13/9/11 | Comedy| C |

But this is not the actual result that I need.

**Can anyone help me the select query to distinct Column Genre and Author from Books and the lastest Date to get this result below?**

| ID |  Date | Genre | Author |

---------------------------------

| 3 | 18/8/11 | Action | A |

| 4 | 3/10/11 | Comedy| C |

| 5 | 16/7/11 | Horror | D |

| 6 | 29/7/11 | Horror | B |

| 7 | 12/5/11 | Comedy| E |

Answer (score 0):

I have been somewhat safe by assuming author names / genre names could be the same, so it uses ID's for locating the appropriate records to the max date sub select records.

```
Select
books.id
, MaxDates.MaxDate
, Genre.GenreName
, Author.AuthorName 
from books
inner join Genre on Books.Genre=Genre.ID 
inner join Author on Books.Author=Author.ID 
inner join
(
  Select 
  max(Books.Date) as MaxDate
  , Genre as GenreID
  , Author as AuthorID
  From Books
  group by Books.Genre, Books.Author
) maxDates on Author.ID = MaxDates.AuthorID and Genre.ID = MaxDates.GenreID and Books.Date = MaxDates.MaxDate
Order By Books.ID Desc;
```

Sub query gets a list of maximum dates per genre / author combination, and then matches this back to the original book records to pick up the book ID in the original record. You need to do that, since you can not just max the id and max the date and assume the max values are from the same row.

Comment: I don't think you need the `INNER JOIN`s on the subquery. You can just use the genre and author ids since they're already in the Books table.

Comment: That's true, I had them in there from the template but they dont need to be, edited them out

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! However I got an error message like this :

Comment: an error like?... I did just notice I had an extra comma in my sql I've removed, since I dont have the tables to test on, the code may need some minor adjustments, but the idea of how it works is fine

Comment: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Books.Genre=Genre.ID
INNER JOIN Author ON Books.Author=Author.ID
INNER JOIN (Select Max(Books.BookDate) as MaxDate, Genre as GenreID, Author as AuthorID From Books
GROUP BY Books.Genre, Books.Author) MaxDates
ON Author.ID=MaxDates.AuthorI' It's okay about the extra comma :D And I also had changed the column "Date" to "BookDate" to avoid error. Now I don't know where this error come from... #__# sorry guys...

Comment: Added a chat room, join that so we avoid a long comment discussion

Comment: Sorry Andrew, I've been trying to join the chat room but the connection here sucked... it won't load. I'm working in a remote area here. And the site said "You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here." :(

Comment: the box to type my text doesnt show in chat room... X_X
please add my ym yaoi_devil@yahoo.com >.<

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the error! Just editing here and there from Andrew's answer.
This is my current syntax to get the result :

```
Select Books.ID, MaxDates.MaxDate, Genre.GenreName, Author.AuthorName
from (( Books INNER JOIN Genre ON Books.Genre=Genre.ID) inner join 
Author ON Books.Author=Author.ID)
INNER JOIN (Select Max(Books.BookDate) as MaxDate
  From Books
  group by Books.Genre, Books.Author) MaxDates 
on Books.BookDate = MaxDates.MaxDate
Order By Books.ID Asc;
```

Thanks a lot for Andrew! XD